# ajax problem in fetching value from response

Tags: ajax, json, grails, prototypejs

I have a function in my controller, `getJson`. It works fine; I am get an AJAX response.

#### Code

```
def getJson = {

// BillingController obj= new BillingController()
//  ResultSet results = obj.showBillingPeriod()
def c= BillingPeriod.createCriteria()

def results = c{

         and{
              max("billingStartDate")
              max("billingEndDate")
         }
   maxResults(1)
      order("billingStartDate", "desc")
 }

   render results as JSON
}
```

#### AJAX

```
  var baseUrl = "${createLink(controller:'billingPeriod', action:'getJson')}"

   new Ajax.Request(baseUrl, {
            method: 'get',
            asynchronous: true,

            onSuccess: function(req) {update(req)}
    });
```

---

```
[{"class":"com.indivar.cmcs.master.BillingPeriod","id":53,"billingEndDate":"25-02-2011","billingStartDate":"28-02-2011","dateCreated":"17-02-2011","enteredBy":0,"lastUpdated":"17-02-2011"}]
```

---

Now I want to fetch the value of `billingEndDate` and `billingStartDate` from `response` and show it in an alert. I tried everything but it did not work. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
onSuccess: function(req) {
   alert(req.responseJSON["billingStartDate"]);
   alert(req.responseJSON["billingEndDate"]);
}
```

Comment: hi thanks , but i am get undefined   i think request that i am get is some thing "[{" different

Comment: @amit4444, are you sure your action is returning content of type `application/json`?